# AWS - EC2 - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, tcp, websocket

I have a websockets application deployed to tomcat on a AWS EC2 instance however I receive the following error in the browser console:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

**This is unlikely an app issue, more likely a connection issue**

The application works fine when deployed locally, and...

- There is no load ballancer in front of my EC2 instance
- I initialise websockets like so: ws://public-ec2-ip-address:80/websocketsservice
- The error: GET /service/servicename HTTP/1.1" 500 1807 is printed in the tomcat logs but no further information
- I have searched for hours and hours online and found many people with similar issues, but no solution
- The application (js/html) loads fine, it's just the websocket connection that fails
- The following security group rules are applied on the ec2 instance:

TCP 80
TCP 22
TCP 443

So... any ideas or pointers would be great. do I need any special configuration to get websockets working?

Comment: I've also now added a security rule to allow all TCP traffic through, but still no luck.